# Which design pattern should I use for my custom JSP tag to report an error

Tags: java, jsp, taglib

I am writing some custom tags in a tag library (Java, not JSP snippets).

Some of them depend on backend services to return data.

Given that the tags will be used by other developers, I would like to help them as much as possible if, for example, they have misconfigured things, or if there are other issues, but I don't necessarily want Exceptions to trickle all the way up and give a 500 error.

Note. This is not MVC. This is a for Model-1 style, page-driven applications.

Architecturally, what is the best, recommended, or established design pattern for the tag to report an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking is (almost) impossible, and breaks the MVC principle. With the MVC principle, here's what you do:

- the controller gets data from backend services and stores them in request attributes
- if there is a problem, the controller can display a custom error page, or can throw an exception which will cause an error 500 to be sent to the browser
- if there is no problem, the controller dispatches to a view which only has to generate HTML from the data stored in the request. No risk of an error here (except for bugs).

If a JSP tag gets data from an unreliable backend service, it's doing it while the view gets rendered and sents HTML to the browser. The HTTP response status (200) has already been sent at this time, and an exception thrown by the JSP tag will only make the page rendering fail. It's too late to display a good-looking error page or to send a 500 error.

The only way around it is to have a filter wrapped around the whole thing, buffering the response in memory, and finally sending the HTML is it rendered successfully. I would really not do that, though. Instead, I would stick to MVC: have the controller prepare the data for the view, and define tags which take data as attributes instead of getting the data from the backend.

If the backend is reliable, but you're only concerned about incorrect usage of the tags (i.e. bugs), the throw an exception with a clear error message and log it, and the developers should be able to figure what the problem is.